# Vue using a method in a v-for statement

Tags: v-for

Can I use a method in a  v-for statement.  For Example

```
<li v-for="attach in item.attachments.split(' ')" :key="attach">
          {{attach}}
</li>
```

Or do I need to split the item.attachments and set it as a different property that is a list

Answer (score 0):

I can do exactly what I asked.  My issue was the field needed to by split by new line feed and not a space.